# Oracle to Mysql %FOUND

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, oracle10g

How can I convert following oracle procedure while loop to Mysql?

```
 WHILE rout_acc_cursor%FOUND
      do something
 END LOOP
```

What is the meaning of using %FOUND?

Answer (score 2):

`%FOUND` Returns TRUE if an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement affected one or more rows or a SELECT INTO statement returned one or more rows. Otherwise, it returns FALSE.

From official documentation. Read about ORACLE cursors [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sql_cursor.htm)

You can create mysql cursor with some `IF THEN` checks, using `last_modify` fields of your table (set `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to this fields). Declare cursor and check if this row modified than `do something`.

If you delete rows - don't really delete them. Just insert `state` field with ENUM of tinyint "DELETED", in other case you miss this rows in your cursor (miss some %FOUND functionality).